If quoted text ends with exclamation/question mark (within the quote), where do you place comma/period?
Example A:

Learn how to write your first "Hello, World!" without relying on IDE.

I decided (please, let's not discuss why) that I need a comma between "Hello, World!" and "without."
Should I place it inside the quotation marks, or outside?

Example B:

Learn how to write your first "Hello, World!"

If this is the entire sentence, Do I need a period here? If so, Does it go inside the quotation marks?


Without the need for a comma in #1 or a period in #2, you might have to decide where to put them according to own your sense of logic and consistency.

This question is similar to: Hello [Comma?] John, If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // Note that the quote, not the matrix sentence, is all that is really important in deciding punctuation.

@EdwinAshworth, why do you believe I should edit my question? Please edit your comment, make it clear how the unrelated question you brought into this conversion is similar and/or how the answers on that question are helpful for my problem. (If you do that, I'll follow the suit and do everything you requested.) // I'm sure the quote helped you decide punctuation in this particular case. The only thing that's missing is for you to actually answer where to put the comma (and period). Thanks

The more upvoted answer at the duplicate is not perfect, but provides valuable insight into how comma usage is viewed nowadays, and advises 'Try reading the following two versions aloud:
• Hello, Jane,
It was a pleasure spending time with you and the children yesterday. //
• Hello Jane,
It was a pleasure spending time with you and the children yesterday. //
Today, speakers of the English language will generally prefer the latter version (that has only one comma after the word Jane) in written form and when read aloud.' This deals with the 'need' for the comma. // The actual ...

question you ask is answered elsewhere on ELU: ' I wouldn't double-punctuate (?,) in this case, as it's best to avoid bloat where not essential' [here, !," or !", // !".]: the ? or ! does 'double duty' rendering an additional comma // full stop redundant (and messy). That's not to say I wouldn't double-[end-]punctuate where I felt it necessary to add clarity/detail. This is generally  better received in the UK than the US. This is also covered elsewhere; I'll try to find it.

Ah ... Sven Yargs' answer at Punctuating a quoted question within a quoted statement (more generally, punctuating a quote within a matrix statement):  << When the requirements of the main sentence and the quotation differ, use the stronger mark. In the examples below the question mark supersedes the weaker full point:
• She was heard to mutter, 'Did you do it?' //
• Can you verify that John said, 'There is only one key to the room'? >> [Oxford Guide to Style]

@EdwinAshworth I guess it's impossible to edit the proposed duplicate after closing? I find the last one you mentioned much more related to this question, and even the one before it is closer than "Hello, John."

@Andy Bonner I'm afraid  can't do it. The first question I mention challenges the need for the comma after 'Hello', and I felt that 'please don't discuss why I feel we need ...' is improper when a false position is encouraged.  Hence the frame challenge. The possible double punctuation at the end of the quote is of course addressed in the other cited questions, as you say.

@EdwinAshworth Ah, but the comma after hello was never in question, and that's what the proposed dup focuses on. The OP is asking about (and doesn't want to "discuss why") a comma after the quoted phrase, i.e. after "world." Btw, it seems in this particular case the internal comma is canonical.

@Andy Bonner Frame challenges are quite on-topic, and this has been addressed. // Dedicated naming protocols are legal rather than strictly EL issues. I believe that 'Biro' once sued someone for genericisation ... but this is not the domain of the site. // As OP didn't state that this was a proper name, the comma choice remains. Someone may have been misled into thinking that the comma in say 'Hello, John' is necessary.

@EdwinAshworth I’m afraid I didn’t quite follow that, but I don’t see a legal issue so much as a reference. The wiki article suggests that, even if anyone were inclined to assert intellectual property, the origins of the phrase get lost in undocumented use long before the first documented one. The point is, “Hello, World!” is a concept (perhaps even a countable one, “a ‘Hello, World’”!), distinct from “hello [anything else],” and the comma was present from 1974 (though, curiously, not the capitalization and exclamation point that seem to have become standardized since then).

As a non-proper-noun, the comma between the two words is optional unless one is actually quoting a text, as with all << Hello, [name/equivalent] >> instances. FWIW, I've not found a single comma in the first 30 hits on Google for "Hello Korea". Ditto for  "Hello, Viet Nam" (though there was one ellipsis here).
